Stuck trying to install self made managed package after successfully creating it
I've successfully created a managed package:
Name                          Value                                                                             
 ───────────────────────────── ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── 
 ID                            xx                                                                
 Status                        Success                                                                           
 Package Id                    xx                                                                
 Package Version Id            xx                                                                
 Subscriber Package Version Id xx                                                                
 Tag                                                                                                             
 Branch                                                                                                          
 Created Date                  2024-08-23 10:47                                                                  
 Installation URL              https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04t... 
 Created By                    005...
                                                            

However, when installing (via the URL, after 30'), the installation link shows the "package not found" page.
EDIT #1
Note that when:
sf package list --target-dev-hub bernardo@...

I get:
 Namespace Prefix Name     Id                 Alias    Description Type    
 ──────────────── ──────── ────────────────── ──────── ─────────── ─────── 
 R2C2_002         R2C2_002 0Hoxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  R2C2_002             Managed 

Which means the package is alright.
I don't know how to continue reviewing the status of the package or the reason it's unavailable. I think there should be a way to check the status or view a log or something.
Any thoughts?

My experience is that there is a delay before the package is available (perhaps the artefacts need to be distributed to multiple environments) though that delay is usually a few minutes so 30 minutes is unusual. But the queued environment has other work passing though it and I have seen many hour delays. Suggest you check for the availability every once in a while and only get concerned after say a day. There is no tool that I know of to check progress.

Thank you. I'll wait... but I don't know "where" the package is and what about its current status.

Yep. It appears created OK in one location, but AFAIK needs to be replicated around the set of servers (hundreds).

Well I've tried after a couple of hours and it didn't work. I'm stuck...
